# Remove arrays that have a matching value from another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
  $arr = Array
  (
      [0] => Array
          (
              [PropertyID] => 11
          )
      [1] => Array
          (
              [PropertyID] => 22
          )
      [2] => Array
          (
              [PropertyID] => 33
          )
      [3] => Array
          (
              [PropertyID] => 44
          )
  )

  $excludeIDs = Array(22, 11, 44);
```

Desired outcome:

```
  Array ( [0] => Array ( [PropertyID] => 33 ) )
```

I want to exclude the arrays that contain a matching PropertyID inside `$excludeIDS`

How may I do this?

Comment: loop through the array and `unset` which are not required.

Comment: `$merged = array_merge($arr, array(array('PropertyID' => 22), array('PropertyID' => 11), array('PropertyID' => 44))); $unique = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $merged);`

Answer (score -1):

Use `unset()` through the array:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
     if(in_array($value['PropertyID'], $excludeIDs)){
         unset($arr[$key]);
     }
}
$arr = array_values($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PropertyID] => 33
        )    
)
```

Comment: Your codepad code is wrong, initial array is two dimensional, not one! Check this one: http://codepad.org/EhHgQEMo

Comment: ohh sorry I didnt see multidimensional array my mistake

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<?php 
$excludeIDs = array(22, 11, 44);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (!in_array($value['PropertyID'], $excludeIDs)) {
        $result_array[$counter] = $value;
        $counter++;
    }

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result_array);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Hey nice try buddy !!!.. Can please elaborate the difference b/w my answer and your. Are you NUTS

Comment: ohh sorry I didnt see multidimensional array my mistake